# PHP - Access JSON data value in array

Tags: php, json

I'm sorry if this is newbie question but I don't understand how to access the `[ids]` value in the JSON array via PHP.

Why is this not working?

```
$jsonResponse = json_decode($response,true);
print $jsonResponse[2]["ids"];
```

This is the JSON array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => analytics#gaData
    [1] => https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=ga:123455&dimensions=ga:eventCategory,ga:eventAction,ga:eventLabel&metrics=ga:visits,ga:pageviews&start-date=2013-01-01&end-date=2020-01-01
    [2] => Array
        (
            [start-date] => 2013-01-01
            [end-date] => 2020-01-01
            [ids] => ga:123455
            [dimensions] => ga:eventCategory,ga:eventAction,ga:eventLabel
            [metrics] => Array
                (
                    [0] => ga:visits
                    [1] => ga:pageviews
                )

            [start-index] => 1
            [max-results] => 1000
        )

    [3] => 1000
    [4] => 9
```

Comment: Please `var_dump($jsonResponse)`

Comment: The above code seems ok with the dump, what's the error you are getting?

Comment: what is the actual json?

Comment: your error message might also be helpful

Comment: your code seems fine. you must have the error somewhere else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with your code. Your code should be printing, what seems to me, the object `ga:123455` *if* the code is executed. When printing this, this object will be converted to a string. PHP will do `(string) ga:123455` (invoke the `__toString()` method on `ga:123455`) to convert an object to a string. If this method is absent, there must be a warning that `ga:123455` cannot be converted to a string. `__toString()` might also return an empty string.

I would suggest debugging it by doing `print var_dump( $jsonResponse[2]["ids"] );` and `print var_dump( (string) $jsonResponse[2]["ids"] );`.

Comment: I tried it and the output is `NULL` and `string(0) ""` with no warnings or other errors. What could be the reason for that?

Comment: Where did you print the var_dump of `$jsonResponse`? After `$jsonResponse = json_decode($response,true);`? Why do you have such a weird output for var_dump anyway (it omits the length of the array and types of the array elements for example)? For the jsonResponse you put in the question, `$jsonResponse[2]["ids"]` would not be NULL. Can you do `print var_dump( $jsonResponse[2] );`?